# Tag search doesn't work in mobile web

Tags: bug, search, mobile-web

Search for tag doesn't work in mobile web. I.e. entering tag  name and then Enter on on-screen keyboard does nothing:

> [image: Tag search in mobile web]

Comment: Broken for me too, on chrome 63 on android 8.0 on a oneplus 3 A3003