# Search tags in mobile version not working at all

Tags: bug, tags, search, mobile-web

In mobile version:

- open [tags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) on any Stack Exchange site
- press search icon
- type anything
- type enter (or suitable sign on mobile keyboard)

Then displayed tags will not changed at all:

> [image]

Comment: I have posted a dupe of the same bug month ago: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304777/339911